# How can I generate input field only for copying string inside?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to generate input field something like this.
How can I?

I figured out this. But is there any smart way to do this for rails?

```
<input type="text" name="url" value="<%= user_path(@user) %>>">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
text_field_tag 'url', user_path(@user)
text_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})
```

Use rails helper to do it.